# Rollupjs throws errors when using @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: rollupjs

I am working on a react  typscript component library and use rollupjs as bundler.
The project runs without errors and bundles as expected.
Now i added an empty file only importing a createSlice:

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

When i run build now, i got the following error:
[!] RollupError: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

If i remove the file again, the build works like expected. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks